# Requirement to pay for quarantine when entering New Zealand?

Tags: covid-19, new-zealand, new-zealand-citizens, quarantine

We are New Zealand citizens who live outside of the country.  We may need to travel to NZ next year for 3+ months (but not permanently), and are currently looking at our quarantine/isolation requirements.  I had heard that there are (or may be) charges related to the quarantine, but on the [NZ Immigration website](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/about-us/covid-19/border-closures-and-exceptions) it only seems to mention charges for critical workers.

> New charges for critical workers will come into effect on 1 January
> 2021.

This web page also mentions fees, but these appear to be application fees, rather than payment for the quarantine arrangement.

> From 10 August 2020, most applicants are charged a fee to apply

I'm fairly sure there are potentially charges for travelers that don't fit into the "critical workers" category.  What charges are there, and is it different for different ages (we're a family of 6 - 2 parents, 3 teens, 1 child)?  Is there any way to reduce or avoid these charges (self-isolation I think is not an option, but perhaps there are other options)?

Comment: Is there a chance you could postpone this trip by 6 months or so? By then, most of New Zealand should be vaccinated and I expect them to allow anyone vaccinated to enter with no quarantine or self isolation.

Comment: @JonathanReez It may be possible - and depending on what charges there are, it may be required!  The nature of our work means we have to return to NZ every couple of years to raise more funds and we are at the end of that.  We've already had to delay our original plans.

Comment: Vaccination won't start in New Zealand's until at least 2Q2021, starting with front line health workers,  those that work at the borders, including MIQ facilities, and vulnerable groups. The government is saying that the borders won't reopen until the vaccination roll out is substantially complete, from which I expect no change until 2022.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a bit hard to find, but the New Zealand government does have a [fairly extensive explanation of the system](https://www.miq.govt.nz/being-in-managed-isolation/charges-for-managed-isolation/). In summary:

- For people who must pay, the cost is "$3,100 for the first or only person in the room (whether that is an adult or a child) with $950 for each additional adult and $475 for each additional child (3-17 years old, inclusive) sharing that room, all GST inclusive." (All costs are New Zealand dollars, of course.)
- There are exemptions for New Zealand citizens, if they are returning for a period of at least 90 days and left before August 11, 2020.
- The charges are different for "critical workers" whose fees are paid by their employers; if you fall into such a category, you should read [the relevant info](https://www.miq.govt.nz/being-in-managed-isolation/charges-for-managed-isolation/charges-for-critical-workers/).

All this is, of course, subject to change on short notice.

Comment: Thank you!  $8,575 for my family of 6, so that's something we'll have to seriously consider.  The exemption if returning 90+ days might be an option - it seems like that would be a one-off but hopefully we wouldn't need it again in 2-3 years time!  I will look for more info on this exemption now.

Comment: Note that the current [next available dates](https://allocation.miq.govt.nz/portal/) for isolation are 75 days in advance, although it may be possible to get an earlier date by lucky timing if someone cancels an earlier date.

Comment: @krubo That is really important to know, thank you.  I didn't know that, and will have to factor that into our planning.  Leaning very heavily toward not going at this stage

Comment: Local media regularly reports that only a small percentage of people pay the fee, maybe you qualify for an exemption: https://www.miq.govt.nz/being-in-managed-isolation/charges-for-managed-isolation/